# Get innerHTML with xpath in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to learn web scraping, even though I checked the examples in the documentation and some questions here at stack I cannot make my code work.

The website I want to scrape has job listings, but there is no pattern or fixed classes on it's structure, almost each element has his own id and individual classes. When I use the inspector to find the xPath of a innerHTML from a anchor tag that it's what I got:

With Firefox:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[3]/div/div/section/ul/li[1]/article/header/div/div[1]/h2/a
```

With Brave Browser:

```
//*[@id="16542952"]/section/div/header/h2/a
```

Same url, and same element, first Job Title from results.

[URL](https://www.catho.com.br/vagas/data-scientist/?q=data%20scientist&page=1)

I want to loop throug the page and get the text from some elements in the Job Listings, like the Job Title, Description, etc.

I am using selenium with Python and Firefox/geckodriver

Comment: I have checked in firefox it's giving same xpath. In brave when copying the xpath select "copy full xpath"

Answer (score 0):

To loop throug the page and get the text of the Job Listings using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)  and *Python* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.catho.com.br/vagas/data-scientist/?q=data%20scientist&page=1')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "header>h2>a")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.catho.com.br/vagas/data-scientist/?q=data%20scientist&page=1')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//header/h2/a")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Analista Data Science', 'Consultor de Data Science', 'Analista Big Data / Cientista de Dados', 'Cientista de Dados', 'Cientista de Dados', 'Cientista de Dados', 'Cientista de Dados', 'Cientista de Dados', 'Cientista de Dados', 'Cientista de Dados']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an element `el`, for example to get it's innerHTML
you can do

```
el = driver.find_element('xpath', 'FULL XPATH (which FireFox gave you)')
el.get_property("innerHTML")
```

And about the loop, I think you could go for the parent element which "holds" the jobs elements by:

```
parent = driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/article/section/ul') # the 'ul' which holds the jobs 'li' tags
jobs = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].children", parent) # the parent variable will be replacing arguments[0]

for job in jobs:
    # do what you want to do to each element
```